# Excel VBA - Tips to improve use of Global Variables

Tags: excel, vba

We're creating a Excel VBA program to create folders and word/excel documents.
The main program will call subs (create folder, create word, create excel), but I also want the subs to be able to act on their own/remember variables without the main program initiating them.

The problem/question: Is there a better way to re-initialize the value of the variable SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG than having to put the SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG = "G:\Administrativt\Automattillverkning av dokument\Zebastian" in every sub routine? This is also the case with variables PROJ_NR, PROJ_BENÄMNING.

Because if I remove that line the subroutines returns a value of 0 for that variable when I try to call it in a standalone situation.

```
Option Explicit

Public PROJ_NR As Integer
Public PROJ_BENÄMNING, SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG, SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT As String
Public DATUM_LEV As Date

Public Sub ABE_Master()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'stänger av uppdatering av skärmen
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'stänger av omkalkyleringar

Call SKAPA_MAPP
Call SKAPA_WORD
Call SKAPA_CHECKLISTA

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub


Public Sub SKAPA_MAPP()

PROJ_NR = Range("PROJ_NR").value
PROJ_BENÄMNING = Range("PROJ_BENÄMNING").value
DATUM_LEV = Range("DATUM_LEV").value

SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG = "G:\Administrativt\Automattillverkning av dokument\Zebastian"
SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT = DATUM_LEV & "_" & PROJ_NR & "_" & PROJ_BENÄMNING

If Len(Dir(SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then

MsgBox "Uppdragsmapp finns redan, inga åtgärder utförda", vbInformation, ""
    Exit Sub
End If

MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT
MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & "Mail"
MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & "Underlag"
MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & "Leverans " & "[" & Year(Date) & "]-xx-xx"

End Sub

Public Sub SKAPA_CHECKLISTA()

PROJ_NR = Range("PROJ_NR").value
PROJ_BENÄMNING = Range("PROJ_BENÄMNING").value
DATUM_LEV = Range("DATUM_LEV").value

SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG = "G:\Administrativt\Automattillverkning av dokument\Zebastian"
SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT = DATUM_LEV & "_" & PROJ_NR & "_" & PROJ_BENÄMNING

If Len(Dir(SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & PROJ_NR & "_" & PROJ_BENÄMNING & 
"_Checklista.xlsm", vbNormal)) > 0 Then

MsgBox "Checklista finns redan, inga åtgärder utförda", vbInformation, ""
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
Wb.SaveAs Filename:=(SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & PROJ_NR & "_" &         
PROJ_BENÄMNING & "_Checklista.xlsm"), FileFormat:=52
Wb.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: `Public Const SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG = "G:\Administrativt\Automattillverkning av dokument\Zebastian"` instead `Public SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG`?

Comment: @АлексейР Is that also true for when I have to grab variable PROJ_NR from a range in the workbook. Will the constant also work there?

Comment: Yes. Declare `Public Const SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG As String = "G:\Administrativt\Automattillverkning av dokument\Zebastian"` at the very top and then you can use the variable `SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG` in `SKAPA_MAPP()` or `SKAPA_CHECKLISTA()` . But remember, you will not be able to change the value of that variable inside the procedure as it is now a constast value.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Great, now what about the other variables, having to insert PROJ_NR = Range("PROJ_NR").value before I'm running the if lenght of dir is > 1. Or else the variable is empty when I want to run the sub routine as standalone.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Under Public Sub SKAPA_MAPP & SKAPA_WORD i run a If statement to check if the file already exists before creating a file. As you can see I have to state the variable PROJ_NR = Range("PROJ_NR").value in all the subroutines. Is it possible to clean up the code and only state it once?

Answer (score 0):

> @SiddharthRout Under Public Sub SKAPA_MAPP & SKAPA_WORD i run a If statement to check if the file already exists before creating a file. As you can see I have to state the variable PROJ_NR = Range("PROJ_NR").value in all the subroutines. Is it possible to clean up the code and only state it once? – MrWZY 16 mins ago

No. Since it is not a constant, you cannot do something like `Public Const PROJ_NR As Variant = Range("PROJ_NR").Value` But you can create a common function to check  if the path exists or not. See this example.

Your code can be reduced to (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Public Const SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG As String = "G:\Administrativt\Automattillverkning av dokument\Zebastian"
Public SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT As String
Public NewFileName As String

Public Sub ABE_Master()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'stänger av uppdatering av skärmen
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'stänger av omkalkyleringar
    
    Call SKAPA_MAPP
    'Call SKAPA_WORD
    Call SKAPA_CHECKLISTA
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Public Sub SKAPA_MAPP()
    If DoesPathExist = True Then Exit Sub
    
    MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT
    MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & "Mail"
    MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & "Underlag"
    MkDir SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & "\" & "Leverans " & "[" & Year(Date) & "]-xx-xx"
End Sub

Public Sub SKAPA_CHECKLISTA()
    If DoesPathExist = True Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    Wb.SaveAs Filename:=(SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT & NewFileName), FileFormat:=52
    Wb.Close
End Sub

Public Function DoesPathExist() As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PROJ_NR As Integer
    Dim PROJ_BENÄMNING As String
    Dim DATUM_LEV As Date
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    PROJ_NR = ws.Range("PROJ_NR").Value
    PROJ_BENÄMNING = ws.Range("PROJ_BENÄMNING").Value
    DATUM_LEV = ws.Range("DATUM_LEV").Value
    
    SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT = DATUM_LEV & "_" & PROJ_NR & "_" & PROJ_BENÄMNING
    
    If Len(Dir(SÖKVÄG_UPPDRAG & "\" & SÖKVÄG_PROJEKT, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Uppdragsmapp finns redan, inga åtgärder utförda", vbInformation, ""
        DoesPathExist = True
    Else
        NewFileName = "\" & PROJ_NR & "_" & PROJ_BENÄMNING & "_Checklista.xlsm"
    End If
End Function
```